# QT background image not showing using stylesheets

Tags: c++, qt, background-image

I'm using QT for C++ and I set this stylesheet code:

```
QFrame {
    background-image: url(img.png);
}
```

The image doesn't show! It's located in the debug directory inside the QT directory. Why doesn't it show?

edit:

doesn't even work with the resource system

edit 2:

It shows now, but only if I use QWidget instead of QFrame. The only problem is that the image repeats when I resize the window. How do I make it stretch normally instead?

edit 3:

OK, I used JUST border-image now and it stretches. However, it's glitchy(if you move a bit fast you can go over the original image), and very slow(if you're not resizing slowly enough, it will stutter and until it manages to stretch there will be a white gap). Can't I get it to resize normally? =/

Using this stylesheet code:

```
QWidget {
border-image: url(:/images/img.png);
}
```

edit 4:

Well if I'm already at it.. what about clickable areas in images? Is that possible?

edit 5:

come on..anyone? this is important

Comment: 'clickable areas in images': Please create a new question (if a search doesn't yield any results) and remove the edit 4 and edit 5 from your original question.

Answer (score 4):

Add your image to resources (.qrc file) of your application.
Then refer to it in your stylesheet:

```
QFrame
{
 background-image: url(:/Style/img.png);
}
```

Comment: I made a new .qrc file, added img.png to there, then clicked on add resource -> background-image and picked img.png. Still didn't work.

Comment: May be other widget covers qframe?

Comment: Yeah! that was the problem! thank you! there's another problem now: Whenever I resize the window the background image repeats and even though I set the main window to be the exact size of the image it doesn't fit right.

Comment: edit: not that it doesn't fit right, it just seems to add a part of the picture at the bottom of the window for some reason... Even if I make the background no-repeat, the image will not stretch and instead when I resize I just see the default window and the part of the image at the bottom of the window moves with the window as i resize. what's causing this?

Comment: May be better try border-image like this: QFrame
{
 border-image: url(:/Style/img.png) 3px;
 border-width: 3px;
 padding: -3px;
 color: rgb(35, 38, 42);
}

Comment: Looks great... But still repeats when I resize the window. And also, I'm doing it in QWidget { }. Doesn't even seem like I have QFrame anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Qt Resource System instead of having an image inside the folder. Images can also be speicified without the url function.